# What is Lifespan value for ID Token?

Tags: token, keycloak

Currently in Keycloak, Access Token Lifespan is configurable and there is no way to configure lifespan for ID Token. How do I configure a lifespan value for ID Token?

Comment: Welcome to SO! In order to post a question you should bring a minimum information as a input sample and expected output sample (if needed), what did you try and your research, in order to show some effort, as SO is not a free coding service. What did you try and research?

Answer (score 1):

Currently in Keycloak, lifespan for ID Token is the same as `Access Token Lifespan`.

Please refer to the code:
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/8.0.0/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/protocol/oidc/TokenManager.java#L765

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't be different ?

From Auth0 https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/id-tokens - ID Tokens are used in token-based authentication to cache user profile information and provide it to a client application, thereby providing better performance and experience. The application receives an ID Token after a user successfully authenticates, then consumes the ID Token and extracts user information from it, which it can then use to personalize the user's experience.

Here are some references which I could gather

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/why-use-access-tokens-to-secure-apis
https://www.ory.sh/docs/hydra/configuration
https://auth0.com/docs/dashboard/guides/applications/update-token-lifetime